# Ubuntu 20.04 Low Disk Space on "boot"

Tags: boot, apt, partitioning, grub2

I'm having problems updating. I'm getting this message about low disk space on boot and I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) which use to work until now. Also this doesn't work `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` it doesn't remove anything. When I do `ls -l /boot` I get this [image]As you can see I tried to delete them manually with `sudo rm /boot/*-5.15.0-50-*`, but I'm not sure if that even worked. How can I remove the old kernels or better yet how can I automate the process so I don't have to do it every time?

My current kernel using `uname -r` is `5.15.0-52-generic`

`df -h | grep /boot*`

[image]

Comment: A few meg you get from removing old kernels will not fix your issue. Why is the root filled? How large was the root in the first place? By killing off all kernels not in use you lose the ability to run an older kernel which sometimes is needed. You never need to remove old kernels manually. It is done automatically when a new kernel is downloaded and installed when there are some old kernels on the system.

Comment: What does `df -h`say?

Comment: @David idk why the old kernel is still around. Does that mean that something on my system is still using it? What should I do?